# multiple dynamic instances of form using python, javascript, or ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I would like to accomplish the following within a single webpage:

Prompt the user to enter an amount of days. Based on the number they enter, multiple instances of a form will be created. So if they enter 5 days, then there may be 5 buttons that appear and they click on each button and fill each form and when they are done entering the values they hit submit when they are done with all of the forms.

I would appreciate any insight on what the best approach would be to accomplishing this. I'm doing some back-end code in python and using JavaScript for the front-end, and I did some reading and I feel like this might be accomplished with AJAX...that is if I am understanding the articles correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: If you plan to have a single submit button then you can just have one form element, and dynamically add groups of fields within that form.

Comment: one form as mentioned and collect data using jQuery `serialize()` then send with ajax. There are lots of tutorials around regarding ajax and forms

Comment: @nnnnnn I am confused as to how to make each form a new instance of the same form with this method..Because what it will do is generate the form as many times as I want but upon submit it will take only the final form values instead of the individual form values for each instance.

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for this suggestion, I will read up on that!